# Databound Dropdown not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I took a check box list control in c# and I data-bound it with a table and now I am trying to access its selected items in a string variable using this code and I took a label too so that it can show which values are selected.

```
string val = this.CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
Label1.Text = val;
```

on debugging this code I receive no values in string and therefore label doesn't prints anything out of the selected items of the databound checkboxlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string text = this.CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Text;
string value = this.CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value ;
```

Have a look at [ListControl.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you huMpty duMpty it worked. In this checkboxlist there are all the usernames are there so that on checking on any numbers I can send them messages the problem again is that when I select multiple users from the list I get only the latest selected user what I want to do is whatever the number of users I select and when I send them the message their separate entries are to be made in the databse. Like this.                                                                            user1             msg1